# How to pass index from Listview.builder to item widget?

Tags: listview, flutter, dart

I want to pass the index of listview items within the Listview.builder to delete these items from it in the item widget.

In the class `Timeline`
I'm having a Listview.builder embedded in a Streambuilder.

```
void removePost(index) {
    setState(() {
      posts.remove(index);
    });
  }

@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    SizeConfig().init(context);
    return Scaffold(
        body: StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
          stream: postRef.orderBy('timestamp', descending: false).snapshots(),
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if (!snapshot.hasData) {
              return circularProgress();
            }
            List<Post> posts = snapshot.data.documents
                .map((doc) => Post.fromDocument(doc))
                .toList();
            if (posts.isEmpty) {
              return Text("No Posts");
            }
            return ListView.builder(
              itemCount: posts.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                final item = posts[index];
                return Post/Item( //??
                  ????? //What comes here? How to pass the index?
                );
              },
            );
          },
        ));
  }
```

In my class `Post` the items are build.
I want to press the Iconbutton to delete the related post but don't know really how to pass the index.

```
class Post extends StatefulWidget {
  final int index;
  final String title;
  final String imageUrl;
  final Function(Post) removePost;

  const Post({Key key, this.index, this.title, this.imageUrl, this.removePost})
      : super(key: key);

  factory Post.fromDocument(DocumentSnapshot doc) {
    return Post(
      title: doc['title'],
      imageUrl: doc['imageUrl'],
    );
  }

  @override
  _PostState createState() => _PostState();
}

class _PostState extends State<Post> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    SizeConfig().init(context);
    return Container(
      height: SizeConfig.blockSizeHorizontal * (100 / 3 + 3),
      child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Text(widget.title),
          Text(widget.imageUrl),
          IconButton(
            onPressed: () => widget.removePost(this.widget),
            icon: Icon(Icons.delete),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@Juju, have you tried,

```
return ListView.builder(
              itemCount: posts.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                final item = posts[index];
                return Post(index: index, title: 'Test', imageUrl: 'https://www.google.com',);
              },
            );
```

Test:

```
class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  MyAppState createState() => MyAppState();
}

class MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        home: Scaffold(
            appBar: AppBar(
              title: Text('Test'),
            ),
            body: Container(
                child: ListView.builder(
                  itemCount: 3,
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                    //final item = posts[index];
                    return Post(index: index, title: 'Test', imageUrl: 'https://www.google.com',);
                  },
                ),
            )
        )
    );
  }
}

class Post extends StatefulWidget {
  final int index;
  final String title;
  final String imageUrl;
  final Function(Post) removePost;

  const Post({Key key, this.index, this.title, this.imageUrl, this.removePost})
      : super(key: key);

//  factory Post.fromDocument(DocumentSnapshot doc) {
//    return Post(
//      title: doc['title'],
//      imageUrl: doc['imageUrl'],
//    );
//  }

  @override
  _PostState createState() => _PostState();
}

class _PostState extends State<Post> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      height: 150,
      child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Text(widget.title + ' ' + widget.index.toString()),// Testing passed index here
          Text(widget.imageUrl),
          IconButton(
            onPressed: () => widget.removePost(this.widget),
            icon: Icon(Icons.delete),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Screenshot:
[image: screenshot]

Comment: that throws an error as it is not known which item should be build. I need to implement the ``` final item``` in the return statement I guess

Comment: so are you not able to see your list at all? Also, your `Post` doesn't take `item` so you can't pass it unless you change your `Post`.

Comment: Check out my edited code, i ran a test and my answer seems to be working fine.

Comment: Yep that works! Is it actually deleting the item when you press the Icon? I'm passing ```return Post(deletePost: deletePost, index: index, title: 'Test', imageUrl: 'https://www.google.com',);``` and calling ```IconButton(
            onPressed: () => widget.removePost(widget.index),
            icon: Icon(Icons.delete),
          )``` and nothing happens :(

Comment: Great. Please mark it as answer to help others with similar question. It wont delete on my end because i don't have your posts but it should work fine for you if you pass it correctly.

Comment: @Pro is there any way i can do this when the data i am working with has another list in it?  for example snapshot.data[index].name works perfectly but   snapshot.data[index].details[index].location    gives a range error and even when i try to reduce the length of the index by doing     snapshot.data[index].details[index > 0 ? index-1 : index].location    it still gives me range error but adds just once item to my list

Comment: @Zaza.codes Yes you should be able to use it with different list. I think your issue is listview item count does not match location list length. You may wanna make your listview item count dynamic depending on the data length like `itemCount: snapshot.data[index].details[index].location.length`

Comment: @Pro [index] cannot be assigned to the itemCount parameter because it is a listview.builder widget i am using and the index parameter is passed in the itemBuilder property, hence  itemCount: snapshot.data[index].details[index].location.length throws an error that index is not defined. Please it would be nice if you have any other method i could use to get this done

Comment: @Zaza.codes could you start a new question with basic runnable code and post your question link here? i'll take a look.

Comment: @Pro done... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64796620/indexing-in-listview-builder